# JNI native class method gets wrong parameter value

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a class:

```
public class api
{
    public static class A
    {
        private native void aNative(long x);

        public A(long x)
        {
            aNative(x);
        }
    }
}
```

And the native method is written in the C file:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_api_00024A_aNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jlong x)
{
    printf("%x\n", x);
}
```

And no matter what value is passed to `x` in the Java file(even if passing `0`), the value in the native method seems weird(looks like a pointer or something, `7f153df073f0`). Also, `env`, `thiz` and `x` have the same value which is weird to me.
Am I missing something? I can confirm that the native method signature is the same as in the generated header file.

Comment: Can you try casting `x` to `long` like this `printf("%x\n", (long) x);`?

Comment: Tried it. Did not work

Comment: Did you get any errors? Or did you get the same output? Can you try printing the `%ld` value for the same and check what does it output?

Comment: Nitpicking here, but technically you have *undefined behavior*. According to [this JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) `jlong` is a "signed 64 bit" integer type, which (currently) corresponds to `long long` in C. The `%x` format expects an `unsigned int` argument. This mismatch in format specifier and argument type is what leads to the UB. You need to use the `%llx` format specifier and explicitly cast to `unsigned long long`. If you build your C code with extra warnings enabled, the compiler should have been able to warn about this.

Comment: It still outputs a weird number.
For context, the `jlong` value in my program should hold a pointer to c native class, and I try to "dereference" it in the native method:
`*(NATIVE_STURCT *)x;`
The interesting thing is that when I do pass 0 to `x`, I get SIGSEGV when trying to access the pointer. maybe that helps?

Comment: No, `jlong` is not a pointer type. It's an integer type, corresponding to the C type `int64_t`.

Comment: I'll edit what I said. It should hold the value of the pointer.
For example, I can confirm that the `x` value in the Java file(In `A` constructor) is correct and has the value which I want it to hold. The problem is that the value in the native method is wrong.
Also, I've tried to output the value with different castings(`unsigned long long`, `void *`) but still I got the wrong results(same result for all parameters, including `env` and `thiz`)

Comment: Can you attach with a native debugger and inspect the stack / registers right after you enter the native function? I cannot reproduce your error locally. Perhaps there is an extra argument before the `long` argument?